# Cannot spatially select from Oracle view based featurelayer in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-spatial

I'm hoping someone has seen this before and has a solution.  I've exhausted all  my ideas.  I having problems with the selection and identify tool in ArcMap.

I have a point feature class, zlevels, and an Oracle spatial view, sv_zlevels, created from zlevels.  I've created a new map in ArcMap 9.3 and added both of them in. When I use the Identify tool and Select Feature tool on the original feature class layer, it works fine.  When I try to do the same on the view layer, I get no results.  I've checked that it is selectable, and that it can Identify from All Layers.  The layer draws fine.  I can change its symbology and labeling.  I can Select By Attribute under the Selection menu but I get no results back when I do a Select By Location.  Its like its not there. If I do the same Select By Location on the original feature class, it works fine.  I have the same set up with a polyline feature class, streets, and I don't have any problems with it.  Streets and zlevels came from the same place - NAVTEQ.  The weird thing is the zlevels had been working.  I can't pinpoint exactly when it stopped since I'm not always working directly in ArcMaps.  And I've had this happen before with zlevels.  I restarted my machine and it seemed to work after that but that may have been a coincidence.  Other have the same problem on their machine when trying to select from sv_zlevels.

What I've tried with no success:

*Dropping and recreating the view in Oracle

*Restarting my machine

*Restarting the server and re-registering the spatial views

Has anyone ever experienced something like this before?

We are running ArcSDE 9.3.1 with Service Pack 1 and ArcGIS Server 9.3.1 with Service Pack 1.  Our version of Oracle is Oracle 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production.  At the end of the week we are going to be updating everything.

Comment: One other thing, if I try to do a spatial query on that layer in ArcObjects, I get back no results either.  So something is screwed up spatially but what??

Comment: In arcobjects, what does IFeatureclass.HasOID return?

Comment: What happens if you export the layer to a gdb featureclass - does it have coordinates?  Does the exported fc's spatialreference match that of  zlevels?

Comment: What version of oracle are you using?
Are user privileges correct?
Lots of Patches (too many too list)
Good source:
http://wikis.esri.com/wiki/display/ag93bsr/ArcSDE+Oracle+Database+Requirements

Comment: i've deleted my answer, but you should leave a comment when downvoting.

Comment: HasOID returns True.  When I export the layer to a gdb feature class, it has coordinates and the spatial references do match. I am also able to select when I exported it as a SDE feature class. See my edit above for version information.  I'm not sure about user privileges. What should they be?

Comment: What happens when you call IFeatureClass.FeatureCount, passing an envelope of a) the full extent (IGeoDataset.Extent) b) a small envelope (around a known point) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was waiting until we installed all the patches before taking more of anyone's time.  We updated both ArcSDE and ArcGIS Server and that seems to have fixed our problem.  I still don't understand why it was working and then seemed to stop.  I'll worry about that if it stops working again.

To answer some of the questions asked, I get the correct count around a known point but zero around the full extent.  I get the same results using the actual table for the layer's data source as I do using the spatial view.

Some more strange things I've found:

- When I'm using the spatial view try to do a map.SelectByShape((IGeometry)polygon, null, false) I get no results.  But when I run the same code using the table, it works ok.
- I plotted the 4 corners of the gdsExtent and found that they are shifted off almost 1500m to the NW of where they should be and the area is about 1/20 the correct size.  This is for the zlevels using either the spatial view or the table as the data source.

So who knows what was going on, but the patches seems to have fixed it.  If it comes up again, I will be back.

Answer (score 0):

I was just wondering if you have registered the spatial View with SDE using the SDELayer command? As you have created a view using the Oracle Spatial objects you may want to manually register with SDE and then the SDE can be the handler for the Object ID here is the script

sdelayer -o register -l table, column -t storage type

Also have a look at this forum posting where they adda an Oracle Spatial Index

http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/11480-No-select-or-identify-possible-on-SDO_GEOMETRY-layer

Comment: We did not try this but this was next on our list if the patches did not work.